# how to maintain angularjs ui grid data in session?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

how to maintain angularjs ui grid data in session? Can anyone give me suggestions how to maintain in session?

```
$scope.applicationGridOptions = {
                enableSorting: true,
                columnDefs: [
                  { displayName:'Name', field: 'name', cellTemplate : '<div><div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><a ng-href=\"#EditHDParam/{{row.entity.hdPerId}}\">{{row.entity.hdRuleName}}</a></div></div>' },
                  { displayName:'Application/Role', field: 'application', cellTemplate: '<div ng-controller="StatusController" ng-if=\"row.entity.status == \'Active\'\" ><img height=\"18\" width=\"18\" src=\'assets/img/on.png\' /><a ng-click="changeStatus(row.entity.dirId,row.entity.status)">Active</a></div>'+
                        '<div ng-controller="StatusController" ng-if=\"row.entity.status == \'Inactive\'\" ><img height=\"18\" width=\"18\" src=\'assets/img/off.png\' /><a ng-click="changeStatus(row.entity.dirId,row.entity.status)">InActive</a></div>'}
                ]
              };
```

i am having grid and i am going to add some values going to store in grid but i need to maintain in session till it goes for db insertion process? Even page is refreshed i need data to be maintain in grid.

Answer (score 0):

Use the $window directive.  So inject $window into your scope, then do something like the following within your controller.

$window.sessionStorage('your data you want to store in session storage').

Afterwords, view the console and type in sessionStorage to ensure your data was saved.

If you want the data to persist even if you close the page, then use localStore instead.  Once again, it has the same exact syntax but you say localStorage instead of sessionStorage.